# How to define constants in Typescript: Define a static class Or define an Object

Tags: typescript, class, constants

I feel a little confusing when I need to define some constants using typescript.

I can define a const like below

```
export const CONSTANTS = {
  db: {
    myDbSessionName: 'mydbconn'
  }
};
```

Or I can define a static class as

```
export class Constants {
  public static readonly db = {
    myDbSessionName: 'mydbconn'
  }
}
```

Could anyone can help to explain what is the difference when using these two ways, such as performance.
And what is the better way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the following example creating a class is unnecessary - you can take a look how tsc will compile your [example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=99#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GEIDs0wq4yYDeAUHHGAK4BGSAlgnASjM3FMCgCZ5IAnnF504AXjgUqVALaCAInQDKwDIzwA5FLOAAuOAHJ5ohHlyHKcAL7lrQA).

I think you should consider creating a class if

- You will have (non-static) instances (even a singleton for lazy init, etc...)
- You have to deal with run-time type checking (e.g. with "inscaneof")
- You want to encapsulate logic in private methods / fields

I don't think there will be any noticeable differences in the terms of performance.

Comment: Hi Lajos Gallay, thanks for your reply. I found one benefit to use Class is it shows how many references of this class in vs code.

Comment: I think you can see the references to any variable, not just classes. Maybe you have to turn on "typescript.referencesCodeLens.enabled" in your config (I don't know if its turned on or off by default) ;)